# Run a script as hidden scheduled task with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, task, scheduled-tasks

I want the word files on the desktop to be moved to the local disk D at the time I set each day.
I've created a scheduled task and code works as follows.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument 'Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Move-Item -Path $home\Desktop\*.doc -Destination D:\ }'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 05:30pm
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

But there is a problem.
I want this task timer to be done in a hidden way, without appearing on the PowerShell window.

To solve this problem I also wanted a way like the following.

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Move-Item -Path $home\Desktop\*.doc -Destination D:\ }'
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 05:30pm
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

Would you help me fix the code I wrote to make the scheduled task run without the PowerShell window appearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a scheduled task in the background configure it to run whether the user is logged in or not. Since you only want to copy files from one local disk to another I'd also recommend not storing the password. `Invoke-Command` should't be required either. Just run `Move-Item` directly.

```
$action    = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument 'Move-Item ...'
$trigger   = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 05:30pm
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" -LogonType "S4U" -RunLevel Highest

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal -Force
```

Comment: Well, I solved the problem.

Can you explain what the values (parameters) you assigned to the `$principal`  variable mean? What do they do?

for example why use `-UserId` ?

`-LogonType "S4U"` What do you mean **S4U** that you are using here?

@Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @HibritUsta "S4U" stands for "Service for User". It's a way of delegating authentication, so that you don't need to store the user's credentials with the task. I never looked into how it works on the technical level, though. Essentially it's the programmatic way of checking the "Do not store password" box when configuring a task to run whether or not the user is logged on. Please see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal) for information about the other parameters.

Comment: Okey, I understand

Comment: When i se `-LogonType "S4U"`` I get access denied.